# Efficient way to compute ROC curve for data stored in BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that contains "score" and "ground truth" field among other things. I want to compute a ROC curve using these two fields.

One solution is to do this in python using scikit-learn. However this requires the usage of BigQuery python API that only returns an iterator over rows. This sounds very inefficient since I have more than hundreds of thousands rows in the table.

I wonder if there's any efficient way to implement this ROC curve directly in a query.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pointers for you:

1. There are Javascript libraries ([one example](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.js.base.node.viz.plotter.roc.ROCCurveNodeFactory)) for you to use with [BigQuery Javascript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure).
2. I'm not familiar with ROC curve, but I assume the algo works on an array of input instead of individual rows. Note that BigQuery doesn't natively support user-defined aggregate functions, you need to do this in a slight hacky way like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION yourFunction(input ARRAY< STRUCT<score FLOAT64, groundTruth STRING> >)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
// Javascript code to calculate ROC curve
""";

-- To use the function in query
SELECT yourFunction(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(score, groundTruth)))
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY some_condition
```

The limitation is, if there are too much data being aggregated into `ARRAY_AGG(...)`, BigQuery may be running out of memory trying to prepare the array as input to your function.

Individual JS UDF call also has 5 minutes timeout.